# Can't use RPi 3 GPIO using computer as power supply

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gpio

I have a raspberry pi 3 that I powered with my computer directly and I can not use the GPIO pins because they don't send anything.

Do I really need a power supplier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you definitely should use a "real" power supply, as mentioned here: [Raspberry Pi, Powers supply](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/hardware-guide/components/power-supply/)
If you use any USB Ports or mobile phone chargers it can happen that some functions are not available, because of lack of power and/or voltage.

Here are the exact specs: [FAQ - Power requirements](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#topPower)

Quote from the FAQs:

[2. CAN I POWER THE RASPBERRY PI FROM A USB HUB?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerHub)

"It depends on the hub. Some hubs comply with the USB 2.0 Standard and only provide 500mA per port, which may not be enough to power your Raspberry Pi. Other hubs view the USB standards more like guidelines, and will provide as much power as you want from each port. Please also be aware that some hubs have been known to “backfeed” the Raspberry Pi. This means that the hubs will power the Raspberry Pi through its USB input cable, without the need for a separate micro-USB power cable, and bypass the voltage protection. If you are using a hub that “backfeeds” to the Raspberry Pi and the hub experiences a power surge, your Raspberry Pi could potentially be damaged."